# Simple threaded timer, sanity check please

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I've made a very simple threaded timer class and given the pitfalls around MT code, I would like a sanity check please.  The idea here is to start a thread then continuously loop waiting on a variable.  If the wait times out, the interval was exceeded and we call the callback.  If the variable was signalled, the thread should quit and we don't call the callback.

One of the things I'm not sure about is what happens in the destructor with my code, given the thread may be joinable there (just). Can I join a thread in a destructor to make sure it's finished?

Here's the class:

```
class TimerThreaded
{
public:

    TimerThreaded() {}
    ~TimerThreaded()
    {           
        if (MyThread.joinable())
            Stop();             
    }

    void Start(std::chrono::milliseconds const & interval, std::function<void(void)> const & callback)
    {   
        if (MyThread.joinable())
            Stop();

        MyThread = std::thread([=]()
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                auto locked = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(MyMutex);
                auto result = MyTerminate.wait_for(locked, interval);

                if (result == std::cv_status::timeout)
                    callback();
                else
                    return;
            }
        });
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        MyTerminate.notify_all();
    }

private:

    std::thread MyThread;
    std::mutex MyMutex;
    std::condition_variable MyTerminate;
};
```

I suppose a better question might be to ask someone to point me towards a very simple threaded timer, if there's one already available somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I join a thread in a destructor to make sure it's finished?

Not only you *can*, but it's quite typical to do so. If the thread instance is joinable (i.e. still running) when it's destroyed, `terminate` would be called.

> For some reason result is always timeout. It never seems to get signalled and so never stops. Is it correct? notify_all should unblock the wait_for?

It can only unblock if the thread happens to be on the cv at the time. What you're probably doing is call `Start` and then immediately `Stop` before the thread has started running and begun waiting (or possibly while `callback` is running). In that case, the thread would never be notified.

There is another problem with your code. Blocked threads may be spuriously woken up on some implementations even when you don't explicitly call `notify_X`. That would cause your timer to stop randomly for no apparent reason.

I propose that you add a flag variable that indicates whether `Stop` has been called. This will fix both of the above problems. This is the typical way to use condition variables. I've even written the code for you:

```
class TimerThreaded
{
...
        MyThread = std::thread([=]()
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                auto locked = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(MyMutex);
                auto result = MyTerminate.wait_for(locked, interval);

                if (stop_please)
                    return;
                if (result == std::cv_status::timeout)
                    callback();
            }
        });
....
    void Stop()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(MyMutex);
            stop_please = true;
        }
        MyTerminate.notify_all();
        MyThread.join();
    }

...
private:
    bool stop_please = false;
...
```

With these changes yout timer should work, but do realize that "[`std::condition_variable::wait_for`] may block for longer than timeout_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays", in the words of [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for).

> point me towards a very simple threaded timer, if there's one already available somewhere.

I don't know of a standard c++ solution, but modern operating systems typically provide this kind of functionality or at least pieces that can be used to build it. See [timerfd_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) on linux for an example.

Comment: To be precise, `terminate` is called. No exceptions are thrown.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anyway.  For some reason result is always timeout.  It never seems to get signalled and so never stops.  Is it correct?  notify_all should unblock the wait_for?

Comment: @Robinson I've expanded on my answer.

Comment: Haha, yes. I added a flag about an hour ago and it seems to work correctly now (I chose std::atomic<bool> so don't need the mutex I assume).